# How to reduce file size of an Android app

Tags: android

I want to reduce the size of my app. It's a recipe app and relies heavily on images. I have over 50 images with total size 2.8MB. The entire app size is 14MB.

I have individual .java and .xml files for each of the 50 recipes. Is there a way to just use one file for all the recipes and call each image from a single file whenever an item is pressed?

Comment: the question which you have asked is too broad. There are multiple ways in which this can be done, depending on the way you currently implement it. In order to reduce the app size, I would suggest you to optimise your images. Need help ?

Comment: When you're using 50 layouts with same structure but different values it's better to use Fragments.

Another solution to reduce app size is to use ProGuard (see https://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)

Comment: ProGuard to for this ?

Comment: With ProGuard the code will be obscured and the result is a smaller app size. But as you have already said is to reduce image size.

Comment: Images are just taking 2.8 MB but the .java files and .xml files takes more!!  I tried to optimize my images but I am unable to do it!! It affects the quality!!

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.recipes.vegetarian_recipes . If you could just open and see this then may be you will get an idea.

Comment: Yeah, you have same logic for each receipe, so you can reuse your layouts with fragments.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.. I already have fragments for all the tabs. Example: My code is like.. if(basic_menus[position] == "Sweet Lime Juice"){
         Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), sweetlime.class);
         startActivity(intent);
        }

Comment: I am just redirecting to its class file after checking the listitem value which in turn will call an xml file. So can I just club all the class files into one single fragment?

Comment: You have to compare strings with `equals` not `==` !

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of different ways to reduce the size of the app. It heavily depends on your needs an requirements.

1. Use a different image file format like jpg
2. Use ProGuard to remove and optimize unused code.
3. Run lint to see if you got unused resources which can be removed
4. Outsource the images to a webserver and download them if you need them. Again this has a lot of other downsides and depends on your requirements.
5. Reuse your layout and code: If you logic and layout is similar in each activity (like it is on your example) think about refactoring the code so you can use one layout and one activity for all similar views.

You said the images only consume about 3mb so take a look at point 5,3 and 2.

Comment: Can you please help me how to reuse the layout and code?